# How to pass array of arguments to Powershell commandline

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to pass array of arguments to powershell script file.

I was trying to pass the commandline like this in command line.

> Powershell -file "InvokeBuildscript.ps1" "z:\"
>   "Component1","component2"

But it doesn't take the parameters it seems. What am i missing? how to pass array of arguments?

Answer (score 31):

Short answer: More double quotes could help...

suppose the script is "test.ps1"

```
param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [string[]] $input_values=@()

)
$PSBoundParameters
```

Suppose would like to pass the array @(123,"abc","x,y,z")

Under Powershell console, to pass multiple values as an array

```
.\test.ps1 -input_values 123,abc,"x,y,z"
```

Under Windows Command Prompt Console or for Windows Task Scheduler; A double-quote are replaced by 3 double-quotes

```
powershell.exe -Command .\test.ps1 -input_values 123,abc,"""x,y,z"""
```

Hope it could help some

Comment: The trick here is to use explicit `-command` instead of `-file`.

Comment: I was able to use `-input_values 123,abc,'x,y,z'`

Comment: Reiterating, what Mike pointed out since I missed it also in this answer. What worked for me was calling Powershell.exe from the batch file with `-command` instead of `-file`

Comment: This doesn't help if you have no control over test.ps1.

Answer (score 11):

try

```
Powershell -command "c:\pathtoscript\InvokeBuildscript.ps1" "z:\" "Component1,component2"
```

if `test.ps1` is:

```
$args[0].GetType()
$args[1].gettype()
```

call it from a dos shell like:

```
C:\>powershell -noprofile -command  "c:\script\test.ps1" "z:" "a,b"
```

returns :

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also pass array variables as command line arguments. Example:

Consider the following Powershell Module

File: PrintElements.ps1

```
Param(
    [String[]] $Elements
)

foreach($element in $Elements)
{
   Write-Host "element: $element"
}
```

To use the above powershell module:

```
#Declare Array Variable
[String[]] $TestArray = "Element1", "Element2", "Element3"

#Call the powershell module
.\PrintElements.ps1 $TestArray
```

And if you want to concatenate and pass the TestArray as a single string of space separated elements then you can call the PS module by enclosing the argument in quotes as shown below:

```
#Declare Array Variable
[String[]] $TestArray = "Element1", "Element2", "Element3"

#Call the powershell module
.\PrintElements.ps1 "$TestArray"
```